# What is a bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

The critical word in my question title is **a**.

I am not asking "*what is bitcoin?*". There are numerous articles that show up when a Google search is performed with that question, and they all involve in summarizing what decentralized currency means, what the blockchain is, how mining generally works etc.

However I find that none actually answer the question of "*what is* **a** *bitcoin"?*

If my child were to ask me "*what is a dollar*"?, I can pull out a one dollar bill or coin for him to hold and examine.

What can I give him to examine when he asks me what a bitcoin is? ([Not counting the physical bitcoin makers](http://www.coindesk.com/10-physical-bitcoins-good-bad-ugly/)) Is there a string of digits I can print out and say "**this!** *this is a bitcoin!*" , or do I point to some entry on a public ledger and say "*there! That's a record of Dad's bitcoin!*"

**Essentially, I would like to know, what is the actual tangible representation of a bitcoin, or any cryptocurrency unit?**

Comment: A one dollar bill is not a dollar.  A one dollar bill is a note that says the U.S. government _owes_ you a dollar.  You can take the dollar bill to your bank and "deposit" it, in which case the government owes the dollar to the bank, and you get a "statement of account" from the bank saying that the bank owes you a dollar.

Comment: @jameslarge Not to wax Libertarian here, but a US dollar _used to_ be an actual tangible asset, because it was backed by gold (and silver).  Now, a dollar is really an IOU on top of an IOU.  Bitcoin is no better, except that the volume of bitcoin isn't in direct control of a government.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with computer programming. Try asking on a Bitcoin-specific forum.

Comment: It’s just numbers in cyberspace, a mirage, insubstantial as pool of water seen over hot desert.

Answer (score -1):

Bitcoin is generated as a compensation for [mining](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining) (running cryptographic calculations to maintain the integrity of transactions within the bitcoin network).

Every block in the blockchain has a specific value (in amounts of bitcoin) and this value is attributed to the bitcoin address(es) who submitted this block successfully.

From the [bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block):

> The number of Bitcoins generated per block starts at 50 and is halved every 210,000 blocks (about four years).

Their value to the outside world depends on what people agree it’s worth (free market if you will).

Comment: But what **is** it? is it a string of digits?

Comment: It’s a compensation for computation. It’s work if you can see it that way. The thing you get rewarded for is a hashed block which contains a specific but previously unknown 32 bit number, such that the hash of the block starts with a minimum amount of 0s.

Comment: Again, this fails to explain what the physical/virtual manifstation of a bitcoin is. I'm not asking what it represents (i.e. I don't care that a $1 bill represents a chip of gold in Fort Knox) I care to know what the bitcoin equivalent of a $1 bill is

Comment: You should care what a 1 $ bill represents though, the answer to what it is is, plainly is: a sheet of paper. There are no bitcoin coins or bills.

Comment: So what is there instead? What do I get to prove that I actually have one bitcoin?

Comment: The bitcoin network has a record of transactions which infer the amount of bitcoin associated with a specific bitcoin address (whose outgoing transactions require its private key). If you have the private key you can use it to transfer bitcoins from this address to another and receive something other than bitcoin in return.

Comment: So "a bitcoin" is in reality a series of lines on a ledger?

Comment: Yeah. Though I wouldn’t say _a_ bitcoin as in _one_ bitcoin, but rather »an amount of bitcoin«.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, a bitcoin can be seen as a measure of work - of "mining" - done by other users. As you probably already know, the entire bitcoin system is pretty much depends on it's users constantly doing difficult computations, sealing and ensuring transactions between users. To ensure that users keep doing those computations (which are quite expensive, by the way, mostly due to electricity and hardware costs), for every block made it's creators are awarded a certain amount of bitcoins, simply for the mere presence of their block in the blockchain. To own a bitcoin is to being able to say "I've been given this bitcoin by that guy, who got it from that guy, who got it from that guy, who got it from lets-skip-these-hundreds-of-transactions from the guy who made that block (very deeply buried inside the blockchain by now) which means he was either very lucky or had a lot of computing power to make that lucky hash and release the block before others could do it". And since every user has a full copy of blockchain on their computer (hopefully correct and agreed by majority), every single transaction ever made can be traced to the source - to the bitcoins awarded for mining a block - and your claim can be easily verified.

Although that's a little bit simplified - since, as in practice, transactions are done in tiniest fractions of bitcoins, the bitcoins you have will most likely originate from different block makers, but in general the concept is the same.

Comment: To keep with the phrasing of the question: **the actual tangible representation of a bitcoin** is a chain of transactions in the blockchain, which can be traced to the block which mined those bitcoins in the first place. Since every participant has it's full copy of the entire blockchain from the beginning of it's existence, everyone can easily verify a claim of any amount of bitcoins.

Comment: So if I wanted to "print out" my bitcoin, I would print out a list of transactions ?

Comment: @CodyBugstein: *Technically*, yes - a list of transactions, along with their signatures and the mined blocks from which that bitcoin came in the first place. However, such printed version alone would not be a valid proof of having the said bitcoin, since nothing stops you from faking that first block and the entire list of transactions in the first place - for a truly valid proof, you would need to print out *the entire blockchain*. Is this a theoretical question about blockchains or do you have a specific goal in mind? (Sorry for somewhat small&blurry reply, but comments can only be so long.)

Comment: Also, why the downvote? Did I misinterpret the question?

Comment: The down vote is because it doesn't answer the question. You explain the btcoin system but not what a bitcoin unit is actually manifested as.

Comment: @CodyBugstein: Oh. I... I thought I just did. To be honest, I'm not sure what else can I add to clarify this. Bitcoin is not a "thing" in a traditional sense; you can't pass it around hands-to-hands as you would pass real cash in form of coins and bills. To give away a bitcoin, you must submit a transaction - and anyone who knows that that transaction was made will know that someone else now has your bitcoin. The bitcoin system is designed so that, ideally, everyone would know of every single transaction ever made and so be able to know who owns every bitcoin by tracing these transactions.